# Testing content of jpa specification

Tags: java, jpa, junit

I have this method that creates a JPA Specification object depending on the user role:

```java
public Specification<Entity> deductSpecificationsFromUserRights() {
        if (datacostUser == null) throw new UnauthorizedException();

        final Specification<Entity> countrySpec = MySpecifications.countryIn(List.of(user.getCountry()));

        return switch (datacostUser.getRole()) {
            case SUPPLIER -> countrySpec;
            case ADMIN -> Specification.where(null);
            default -> throw new UnauthorizedException();
        };
}
```

Is there any solution to test with JUnit the content of the specification ?
For example in case of an Admin user, the specification is empty, in case of a Supplier user, I should find something related to the country ?

I can't find any solution for what I would like to do.
The code is working, the sql is well generated by jpa, but I would like to prevent any change in the future that would broke this tests (unless the change is requested). I am not testing on a database, but I would like to make sure that the query has the good filters.